# Codeigniter confusing with $this->db queries

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to access data by using another model's method in my model but it gives me error because it confuses by previous $this->db parameters:

```
        $this->db->select('*');

        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('title',$keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('keyword',$keyword);
        $this->db->group_end();

        $locations = $this->place_model->search_ids_by_name($location);
```

and the search_ids_by_name() of Place_model is like this:

```
  public function search_ids_by_name($q) {
          $this->db->select('id');
          $this->db->like('name',$q);
          $qry = $this->db->get('places');
          $results =  $qry->result_array();
          $place_ids = array();
          foreach ($results as $result) {
            array_push($place_ids, $result['id']);
          }
          return $place_ids;
  }
```

But it gives me below error

> Error Number: 1054, Unknown column 'category' in 'where clause' 
>   Filename: models/Place_model.php

It seems in my place_model function also using like and or_like methods. How can I seperate them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I made another connection:

```
public function search_ids_by_name($q) {
        $places_db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $places_db->select('id');
        $places_db->like('name',$q);
        $qry = $places_db->get('places');
        $results =  $qry->result_array();
        $place_ids = array();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
          array_push($place_ids, $result['id']);
        }
        return $place_ids;
}
```